# Why the array not continue where the last number insert?

Tags: c, arrays

My idea is to make this program to first queue the number (start from 1001)until 10 loop.But at the same time every twice loop. i want it to delete the first number insert.Then it continue insert number after the last number insert. For example. (0) insert 1001,(1) insert 1002,(2) delete 1001,(3) insert 1003,(4) insert 1004,(5)delete 1002. This is what i imagine and the desire output. But now. When it delete it reset to the initial number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10 /* The maximum size of the queue */
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert(int queue[], int *rear, int value)
{
    if(*rear < MAX-1)
    {
        *rear= *rear +1;
        queue[*rear] = value;
        printf("\n%d queue at counter 1",value);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe queue is full can not insert a value\n");
        exit(0);
    }
}
void delete(int queue[], int *front, int rear, int * value)
{
    if(*front == rear)
    {
        printf("\nThe queue is empty can not delete a value\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    *front = *front + 1;
    *value = queue[*front];
    printf("\n%d left counter 1",*value);
}

int main()
{
    int queue[MAX];
    int iCounter,front,rear,loop=0,a,b,c;
    front=rear=-1;
    a=1001;

    do{
        printf("\n------------------------------");
        printf("\n\tWelcome!!\n");
        printf("\n------------------------------");
        printf("\nPress which counter you prefer");
        printf("\n1-Pay bill");
        printf("\n2-Check up");
        printf("\n3-QnA");
        printf("\n------------------------------\n");
        scanf(" %d",&iCounter);
        loop++;

        switch(iCounter)
        {
            case 1:
                insert(queue,&rear,a);
                a++;
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nError input!");
                break;
        }

        while(loop==2)
        {
            delete(queue,&front,rear,&a);
            loop=0;
        }

    }while(rear<MAX-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite your explanation it is not very descriptive and I have a hard time understanding what you want to say.

Comment: Include front as well in your insert function, as initially for first element it should be set to 0.

Comment: I don't see what your program tries to accomplish. You just count up front and rear, so after max 10 calls to `insert` you would not be able to add another one because you never decrease rear in delete you just count up front... also you if you delete something a will be set to the first value again. So the next added value will be the one you deleted. Is this intended?

Comment: You are incrementing rear, but print out icounter

Comment: @KamiKaze i want it to insert the last number it stop. not reset the number to initial.

Comment: @ShayGold oh i just want to display that the number already can line up on that particular counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your delete function take the address of `a` and writes the deleted value into it. So it will get set to the value you deleted.

You could just remove 
`*value = queue[*front];` 
and change

`printf("\n%d left counter 1",*value);` 
to

`printf("\n%d left counter 1",queue[*front]);`

and also remove the whole parameter and then I think it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

your delete() function pass a as pass by reference that's why you did not get what you want

```
delete(queue,&front,rear,&a);
```

For your design you should pass a as pass by value

```
delete(queue,&front,rear,a);
void delete(int queue[], int *front, int rear, int value)
```

Comment: there is no need to pass value at all, because it will never be used

Comment: @KamiKaze yes we can do also without it. But i want to show what wrong he was doing.